# Make Android App just for accesing data from excel file (online or offline)

Tags: android, excel, database

Im new here and also new in Android World.
I wanna make an application for accessing data from excel file by typing some code. Its like Vlookup fuction in Excel.
So, what should I do in general and spesific to make it real.

Answer (score -1):

1. Read excel file from local
2. Work with Workbook, Cell, Sheet, Row objects. VLOOLUP is just for Excel file, now in order to find something, you must write java code

Ref: http://www.cuelogic.com/blog/creatingreading-an-excel-file-in-android/